# How to obtain the value of a cell daily and store it on a column each new row representing a new day?

Tags: google-sheets

what I want to accomplish is being able to obatin the value I have on one cell on a daily basis and store it on a column and each new row will represent one new day.
For example: I have a value on cell A1= 2, and I want to keep track of that value over time, today the value will be stored on B1= as 2, the lets say I change the value of A1 = 3, then tomorrow the value will be taken and added to B2= as 3.
I have been tried different things but my knowledge of google sheetis very limited.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Automatically Store Data.

I understand that you are trying to create a sheet that will automatically store the data daily on your cell B1. I understand that you are trying to accomplish this using Google Sheets only, however automatic triggers are not supported with Google Sheets. Google Apps Script is the best way to make it happen. You just need to attach a script with an automatic trigger to do it for you.

I have created a sample that will help you get started. It will create a basic functionality of transferring the value of A1 to First Vacant Cell on B1, and create a Day Stamp on C1 on the same row with your Daily Data. I have created a Time Driven event so the script will always be run everyday.

```
function  createTimeDrivenTriggers() {
 ScriptApp.newTrigger('getData').timeBased().everyDays(1).create(); 
// This line of script will let you automatically run the getData everyday.


  
}

function getData(){
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet1");
var dateToday = new Date();
var dateOnly = dateToday.getDate();
var monthOnly = dateToday.getMonth();
var yearOnly = dateToday.getFullYear();
var dateForDisplay = monthOnly + "/" + dateOnly + "/" + yearOnly;
var dataToday = ss.getRange("A1").getValue();
var lastRow = ss.getLastRow();
ss.getRange(lastRow + 1, 2).setValue(dataToday);
ss.getRange(lastRow + 1, 3).setValue(dateForDisplay);
//These functions are taking care of getting the date and current value of A1 then add it to your column.

}
```

I understand that you are new to Google Sheets. I have taken the honor of compiling some helpful links, articles that will provide you examples and references on Google Apps Script that will multiply the productivity of your Google Workspace Core Services like Google Sheets, Docs, Gmail and many more.

Here's what it looks like on your Google Sheet:
[image]

### References:

[Google Apps Script Homepage](https://www.google.com/script/start/)

[Google Apps Script Spreadsheet Services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet)

[Trigger Events](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#time-driven_triggers)

Comment: Thank you, this was able to help with what I wanted to accomplish.

Comment: Once getmonth() starts from 0, I suggest use ```var monthOnly = dateToday.getMonth() + 1;``` to get the correct current month.

Answer (score 0):

You can acheive this without script if you are willing to enable iterative calculation. If you do this, then circular references are allowed, and we can generate self-referencing IFs which can inherit the value of A1 if some condition is true, otherwise they simply hold their current value. So, given your example, you could try the following in B1 (N.B. I am writing this on the 6th May 23 for which the datevalue is 45052):
`=if(datevalue(today())=45052,A1,iferror(1/(1/B1)))`, and the following in B2: `=if(datevalue(today())=45053,A1,iferror(1/(1/B2)))`.

Any value added to A1 today will then be replicated in B1. When the clock ticks over to tomorrow, B2 will now replicate the value entered in A1, but B1 will remain unchanged with whatever the last value in A1 was before the date changed.

Answer (score 0):

I will add to @Babanana answer. I replaced

```
var dateToday = new Date();
var dateOnly = dateToday.getDate();
var monthOnly = dateToday.getMonth();
var yearOnly = dateToday.getFullYear();
var dateForDisplay = monthOnly + "/" + dateOnly + "/" + yearOnly;
```

With:

```
var dateForDisplay = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT+1", "dd/MM/yyyy")
```

Adjust date format and GMT time based on you location.
Another thing I added to the trigger is time, 0-23 format (3 pm):

```
ScriptApp.newTrigger('getData').timeBased().everyDays(1).atHour(15).create();
```